# Using BroadcastReceiver peekService without an Activity binded to my Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I need to implement a service whos periodically scans for the avaliables wifis networks, and save that information for use whenever I want to. To do that, I've implemented a service who gets started when the android boots, and I want that service always running, indepent from my Activities. I want to access the scan data from a Broadcast Receiver, and to access that, im using the peekService method from the Broadcast Receiver class. My problems is that, the peekservice returns null if my Service (who Im sure is running) isn't binded to an Activity. So for test, I've binded my service with my main activity using the bindService() method, and with that, the peekService don't return null. But I really want to use that data without have to bind an Activity to the Service, anyone knows how to do that?

PS: I don't want to pass a intent from the service to the broadcast receiver either, I want to use the data with my "get" method, because I want to access the informations when I need to, and not when the scan is completed.

Thats my broadcast receiver to start the Service

```
public class StartMyContextCollector extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ContextCollectorService.class));


        }
    }
}
```

Thats my Service

```
public class ContextCollectorService extends Service {
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    private ArrayList<Bundle> wifiEvents = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    List<ScanResult> scanList;
    WifiListReceiver wifiReceiver;


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ContextCollectorService getService(){
            return ContextCollectorService.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return new LocalBinder();
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReceiver = new WifiListReceiver();
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    }

    public ArrayList<Bundle> getWifiEvents(){
        return this.wifiEvents;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        wifiManager.startScan();

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    class WifiListReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            Bundle numberWifis = new Bundle();
            numberWifis.putString("NUMBER_OF_WIFI", String.valueOf(scanList.size()));
            wifiEvents.add(numberWifis);
            for (int i = 0; i < scanList.size(); i++) {
                Bundle wifiEvent = new Bundle();
                wifiEvent.putString("SSID", scanList.get(i).SSID);
                wifiEvent.putString("BSSID", scanList.get(i).BSSID);
                wifiEvents.add(wifiEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That what im doing to get the information that I want in my Broadcast Receiver

```
ArrayList<Bundle> wifiEvents = null;
        IBinder binder = peekService(context, new Intent(context, ContextCollectorService.class));
        if (binder != null) {
            ContextCollectorService service = ((ContextCollectorService.LocalBinder) binder).
                    getService();
            wifiEvents = service.getWifiEvents();

        }
```

in my main Activity, I created a connection and used the bindService method on the onStart() command, binding the Activity with the Service, but that's what I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [peekService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#peekService(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) does not fully describe the conditions required to get an IBinder.  As Dianne Hackborn (Google Android engineer) explains in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/yiq_XIzFoS4): "Calling `startService()` is not enough -- you need to have called `bindService()` for the same intent, so the system had retrieved the `IBinder` for it".  Your results confirm this behavior: You get an `IBinder` when you have previously bound the service to an activity, but not when the service has only been started.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the peekservice only works with the service binded with an Activity... I fix my problem using a singleton class and storing my informations there, it's the only way I figure it out how to do what I was trying to do, anyone know a different approach for that?